# firewalld ignoring source

Tags: linux, centos, firewalld

I have a CentOS8 box, and a default config of firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I add a range i'd like whitelisted, I'd like to allow 10.21.0.0/16 and block everyone else:

```
firewall-cmd --add-source=10.21.0.0/16
firewall-cmd --add-source=10.21.0.0/16 --permanent
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 10.21.0.0/16
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But when I try to ssh from a box with an IP of 158.121.110.66 it goes through. Shouldnt it block everything but 10.21.0.0/16? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the firewall to deny all connections, except specific sources,
you should set the default zone to be, e.g. `drop` or `block`:

```
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=drop
```

Of course, you have to be very careful when applying such things :-)